# What is the best approach to get the data from a single interface pin ultrasonic sensor?

Tags: arduino, proximity-sensor, ultrasound, teensy, proximity

I am using a Teensy 4.1 to get the data from the TDK [B59150X0754P030](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/sensor/ultrasonic/tof/data_sheet/b59150x0754p030.pdf) sensor.

The sensor is working on 8 to 12 VDC. Three pins are there to get data (Vin, Sig, and Gnd).

The Sig pin is bidirectional and works on a 12 V logic level. I am aware of logic level shifters, but all level shifters are double-channel bi-directional not single-channel bi-directional. So can you suggest a way to get data from this sensor?

One way in my mind is to use a bidirectional double-channel voltage level shifter and switch it using transistors to get data and send pulses. Still, I am worried about the switching frequencies and data corruption.

Only one wire is utilized to send a pulse and receive a pulse, the nominal voltage of that data pulse is 12 V, so the voltage level is not only one way, a single channel has to be capable to handle both directions based on signal direction.

I found a partial solution: I can use a direction-sensing type voltage level shifter (TI [TXB0104](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/txb0104)).

Comment: The signal pin looks like it requires an external pull-up so, what makes you think it is 12 volt logic?

Comment: Isn't a "bidirectional double-channel voltage level shifter" a 2-channel, each channel being bi-directional, shifter?  **Why not just use 1 channel of your shifter chip**?  Or, is it the 12V spec that's causing you problems?

Comment: Had to search out the data for the Elmos chip that is in the device. For all intents we can consider the interface 12V logic. “All level shifters are double channel”? That’s a broad statement - which level shifters are you referring to?  Driving the device is simply a npn bjt or a little mosfet like a bss138. Receiving the data is a simple resistive divider. As for ‘best’ - that depends what is best for you as there’s many valid solutions. Would best be ‘using commonly available components’? If you have performance concerns, state them specifically. Engineers work with facts and numbers.

Comment: This line is in the FAQ "The minimum voltage for the sensor to start up is around 8 V. The nominal supply voltage is 12 V, so a DC-DC converter and a level shifter for the IO line is required."

Comment: Looks suspiciously alike to Elmos 524.xx series chips that support a 3-wire interface. Try searching for **Elmos AN0266** application note perhaps?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

BS170 solved the interfacing problem.

Here I found a well-described blog on bi-directional voltage level shifting https://www.digikey.com/en/blog/logic-level-shifting-basics

Comment: Can you expand this answer so if the link goes down it's still relevant?